# combine two arrays into associative array, problems

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I had a problem where I couldn't insert data into a `table` because the `columns` were not named correctly. They were simply column1, column2, etc. Instead of Date, Address, City, etc. I did not design this database and there is no way for me to change how these tables are made so I decided to `insert` the names of the `columns` in the first `row` below them. Now I have a corresponding piece of data to link them together. So now I am making an `array` of all the column names, and an `array` of all the values in `row` 1 so I can combine them into one `associative array`. I will later use this as a key for my insert statement.

That may of been confusing so here is what my `table` looks like

```
id | column1 | column2 | column3
 1 |   Date  | Address |  City
```

However the next time it could have more columns, with different names so it would look like this

```
id | column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 
 1 |  Apple  | Orange  | Tomato  |   Pear  | Banana
```

Now here is the code I'm using to try and make my `Associative Array`:

```
$col_keys = array();
$col_values = array();

$columns = "SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'mytablename'";
$columns_info = "SELECT * FROM 'mytablename' WHERE 'id' = '1'";    

if ($query_run11 = mysql_query($columns)) {
    if (mysql_num_rows($query_run11) == NULL) {             
            $response["success"] = 0;         
            echo $response;
    } else {        
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run11)) {            
            $col_keys['key_name'] = $row['column_name'];                        
        }           
    } 
}

if ($query_run12 = mysql_query($columns_info)) {
    if (mysql_num_rows($query_run12) == NULL) {             
            $response["success"] = 0;         
            echo $response;
    } else {        
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run12)) {            
            $col_values['value_name'] = $row['column_name']; // PROBLEM                     
        }           
    } 
}

$final = array_combine($col_keys, $col_values);
//echo '<pre>'; print_r($final); echo '</pre>
```

As commented in the code the line below is a problem.

```
$col_values['value_name'] = $row['column_name'];
```

It's a problem because `'column_name'` is not the name of the column. Obviously that was the whole problem to begin with, there's no way to know what the column name is. It could be column1 - column 67.

So my question is how would I do this?

Also if there is an easier way to do ***all of this*** I'm all ears. This is a poor solution but it was the best I could come up with so far.

**EDIT**

There seems to be a lot of confusion on my overall goal. It's understandable as this database design sucks and its a complex problem. The column names are actually the value of the question. The rows underneath them are the answers to those questions. So eventually this is my goal. I will have an `Associative Array` that looks like this

```
column1 => Date
column2 => Address
column3 => City
...
```

That way I can write an INSERT that inserts `06-22-2013` (the answer to Date) into `column1` because `column1 => Date`.

If more explanation is needed I will add to this.

Comment: Why do you not know the name of the columns, aren't they column1 and so on?

Comment: @silkfire they are, but they will be column1, column2, etc. So it's not like I can say `$row['column1'];`. If I'm wrong let me know. Also the whole reason behind all of this is these tables are full of questions, and the questions will be different each time. So what the column names should be will be different each time. Next time the table might have column names of "apple, banana, pear". Which is why I need to create this associative array each time before I make my insert statement otherwise I will never know where to put the values

Comment: Is it different number of columns for each time, besides different names?

Comment: @silkfire yes, It could be 10 questions the first time, which would be 11 columns (including the 'id' column) and then 650 the next time. However the number of columns, and the number of questions are always the same. So an associative array makes sense because both array will always be the same length

Comment: Why not separate table with associations column_i<->name?

Comment: @user161722 honestly? I have no idea, I didn't even know I could do that. SQL/PHP is not my strong suite. I use Java for Android 90% of the time. If you think you can write some code for that solution and it will be more elegant/cleaner than this I am very open to that suggestion

Comment: Yes could be. You do not have $row['column_name'], you have $row['column1'] in the row with PROBLEM

Comment: @user161722 but what happens when I need the info from `$row['column2']`? Because I will never know how many columns there will be, so I cannot hardcode each one to say `$row['column2']` `$row['column3']` `$row['column4']` etc

Comment: Like `$row['column' . $i]`, providing you know when to stop, but see my answer down also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, switch to PDO or MySQLi, see big warning [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php); this is PDO code:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_name', $user, $pass);
$stmt = $dbh->query($columns_info);
$result = $stmt->fetch();
$col_values = $result;
```

After that you can combine them:

```
$final = array_combine($col_keys, $col_values);
```

But inserting different kind of data into a same column... looks like a problem. Just populate a separate table like:

```
+------------+-------+
| column_id  |  name |
+------------+-------+
```

every time, and clear it after use. `column_id` could be 1,2,3... with AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: I tried using PDO and I can't get it to work. It never actually performs the queries this way. I think it's the database I'm working with.

Comment: That's actually a really good idea about the separate table though. I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: PDO will connect same way, see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php), your db has nothing special.

Answer (score 1):

the column names are already in array.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'mytablename' WHERE 'id' = '1'";    
$query = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($query) == NULL)
{
echo 0; 
}
else
{

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
$id=$row['id'];

// you build your out in here.

$id[$id]=$id;
$date[$id]=$row['column1'];
$address[$id]=$row['column2'];
$city[$id]=$row['column3'];


}


}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: by this logic then all I need to do is have take `$columns` and `$columns_info` and just combine them? like this - `$final = array_combine($columns, $columns_info);` ???

Comment: what do you want to do with the data?

Answer (score 1):

Just perform a regular INSERT, specifying `null` as the first value so that the id  column auto increments correctly.

Comment: My whole problem is the column names represent questions. The insert statement represents the answers to those questions. So `Weight` would be the column name where as `177.5lbs` or `391.2kg` would be the answer inside the row. If I perform a normal insert it has no idea what order to put the data in and it will stick `Phone Number` under the weight column and any other number of whacky outputs

Comment: You do know that the whole table design is royally screwed, it is the completely wrong way of building a table...

Comment: Now that being said, once this associative array is complete, I will perform an INSERT based on `column1 => Weight`, so INSERT `177.5lbs` into `column1`

Comment: Oh yes my friend, I know all too well how poorly this was designed =). This database is a nightmare. I had no idea what I was getting into when I started to design my Android App.

Comment: Hmm, and there's no API you can use? It doesn't make sense that the column name is a question. You can't put any characters you want in a column name, you know =S

Comment: at this point I think it would be easier to give you the log in information for this horrid database, show you the nightmare I've been working with and see if you can fix it. Because I am losing my mind trying to figure this out, lol. BTW thank you very much for even attempting to help me

Comment: Awesome, let's see if I can make sense of this db of yours. Giving no promises though ;)

Comment: I'm actually need to go to sleep now is it okay if I help you out tomorrow instead? I don't know how to get Gmail chat to work on my Android phone but I messaged you on Hangouts lol.

Comment: no worries, I am sending you a detailed email. Get back to me tomorrow if you figure it out. Otherwise I'm sure I'll be on here asking more questions. =)